# Webpack Throws Multiple-Chunk error when compiling with Dart-SASS

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-5

I am trying to use SCSS on a webpack project. From the official documentation on the sass-loader (which you can see here: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) I copied the configuration file. But compilation fails because of `Error: Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename main.js (chunks index and runtime)`. What's more is that the same error shows up even when I don't import the SCSS file in my index.js. I have failed to see what's missing.

My webpack.coinfig.js file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devServer: {
    static: './dist'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single'
  },
  // to use SASS
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              // Prefer `dart-sass`
              implementation: require("sass"),
            },
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

All my files are in this github repository: https://github.com/black-RAM/kajs-cooking.

Answer (score 0):

I came back to this problem in the evening, and realised I had made the mistake of forgetting to actually install the style-loader and css-loader. For anyone who is following the guide, note that it assumes you already have those loaders installed, so don't forget too. Secondly, I removed the optimizations property. That's what resolved the build errors. Hope this helps anyone out there with the same issue.